# R - How to add SpatialLine attributes to its endpoint?

Tags: r, attributes, spatial

Given is a SpatialLine and a Spatialpoint at its end.
An attribute of the line (e.g. the length) should be add as information to the point. How to do this?

```
library(sp)

l1 = cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(3,2,2,4))
rownames(l1) = letters[1:4]
Sl1 = Line(l1)
Ll1 = Lines(list(Sl1), ID="a")
Sl = SpatialLines(list(Ll1))

Sl_length<-SpatialLinesLengths(Sl,longlat=FALSE)

pts = cbind(4,4)
dimnames(pts)[[1]] = letters[1]
df = data.frame(a = 1)
row.names(df) = letters[1]
SpatialPointsDataFrame(pts, df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
library(raster) 
Sl = spLines(cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(3,2,2,4)))
pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cbind(4,4), data.frame(a = 1))
```

You can do

```
pts$Sl_length <- SpatialLinesLengths(Sl, longlat=FALSE)
```